# SQL Query Removing Dups

Tags: sql

Using GoldMine CRM and wrote this query to try and find out people in our system based on a record Type, Lead Creation Date and Last Contact Date. Now when running the query it brings up multiple results say for John Smith it is showing me all of his information rather than just the last contacted date which I want. I'll paste the query below any help would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONTACT1.CONTACT    AS Contact_Name, 
                Min(CONTACT1.CONTACT), 
                CONTACT1.KEY1       AS Rec_Type, 
                CONTACT1.CREATEON   AS Lead_Type, 
                CONTHIST.LASTDATE   AS Last_Contact, 
                CONTHIST.RESULTCODE AS Stamp 
FROM   CONTACT1 
       INNER JOIN CONTHIST 
               ON CONTACT1.ACCOUNTNO = CONTHIST.ACCOUNTNO 
WHERE  CONTACT1.KEY1 = 'Lead' 
GROUP  BY CONTACT1.CONTACT, 
          CONTACT1.KEY1, 
          CONTACT1.CREATEON, 
          CONTHIST.LASTDATE, 
          CONTHIST.RESULTCODE 
HAVING Count(CONTACT1.CONTACT) = 1 
ORDER  BY CONTACT1.CREATEON
```

Comment: So you want just one row per contact, the one with the most recent contact date?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: This does work but is only bringing up contacts/records that only have one stamp and missing out other contacts. I have altered my code a bit as I don't think I need the MIN

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT
CONTACT1.CONTACT AS Contact_Name,
CONTACT1.KEY1 AS Rec_Type,
CONTACT1.CREATEON AS Lead_Type,
CONTHIST.LASTDATE AS Last_Contact,
CONTHIST.RESULTCODE AS Stamp
FROM
CONTACT1 INNER JOIN CONTHIST ON CONTACT1.ACCOUNTNO = CONTHIST.ACCOUNTNO
WHERE
CONTACT1.KEY1 = 'Lead'
ORDER BY 
CONTACT1.CREATEON

Comment: Robert Stephen Lead 2014-04-23 00:00:00.000 2014-06-12 00:00:00.000 GOA
Robert Stephen Lead 2014-04-23 00:00:00.000 2014-07-15 00:00:00.000 NA
Robert Stephen Lead 2014-04-23 00:00:00.000 2014-07-17 00:00:00.000 
Robert Stephen Lead 2014-04-23 00:00:00.000 2014-07-23 00:00:00.000 NA
Robert Stephen Lead 2014-04-23 00:00:00.000 2014-07-30 00:00:00.000 NA

Comment: I only want it to show the most recent last contact on date and not the rest